# What is the meaning of $1 and $2 in the Blade::extend function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I saw this example in the [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates#extending-blade):

```
Blade::extend(function($view, $compiler)
{
    $pattern = $compiler->createMatcher('datetime');
    return preg_replace($pattern, '$1<?php echo $2->format(\'m/d/Y H:i\'); ?>', $view);
});
```

but I don't seem to understand it, and some time the examples in the web include $3.

I didn't find a proper answer to this through a Google search, I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a string replacement! It replaces the variable (e.g. `$1`) with the matching group of the pattern!

As example (Pseudo Code):

```
$pattern = "/(.*?)([a-z])/";
//Here is $1 ^ This group and $2 would be the second group
```

Also as additional help:

[PHP regex Cheat Sheet](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse190m/12sp/cheat-sheets/php-regex-cheat-sheet.pdf)

[Online Regex tester](https://regex101.com/) (<- It visualizes the match of your regex very nice and explains the different parts of your regex)

Comment: I got it even more when I saw the code of `$compiler->createMatcher()` function the first group will refer to `@` then the value that passed then the parameters that it could be inside this extended function of blade.